# Why does Spark Streaming need a certain number of CPU cores to run correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, spark-streaming

The [Spark Streaming documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/streaming-programming-guide.html) notes:

> it is important to remember that Spark Streaming application needs to
>   be allocated enough cores to process the received data, as well as, to
>   run the receiver

and then:

> If the number of cores allocated to the application is less than or
>   equal to the number of input DStreams / receivers, then the system
>   will receive data, but not be able to process them

This seems surprising as OSes would schedule CPU such that the application progresses, regardless of how many CPU cores are there unless it's somehow prevented from doing so. My questions are:

- Does Spark do something special to prevent normal CPU scheduling?
- If so, what's the rational behind it?

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that they must mean 'thread' by 'core'. If there are not enough threads, it will certainly lead to thread starvation. Inline with this, I could create a local cluster with more 'cores' than the physical cores available (e.g. `"local[10]"` on a machine with only 4 CPU cores).

Comment: "cores" is a bit overloaded here. It means the number of simultaneous tasks Spark will attempt to execute. This is expressed as "the number of cores to take". Yes, it's like the number of different threads Spark will attempt to use. For local, you might well be able to specify more cores than you have. For YARN it wouldn't work since it actually looks to reserve entire cores.

Answer (score -2):

No, it looks that the documentation is correct and means physical CPU cores, not threads.
Starting six readers on a 4-core machine will cause the whole Spark Streaming application to stall, even with --local[10]. At the same time, the same app runs flawlessly on the machine with 8 cores.